# Find out who activated which feature in Google Kubernetes Engine resp. Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, audit, administration

Istio has been recently activated on the Google Kubernetes Engine cluster we are using. However we don't know who of our team did it.

Is there a way to find out who activated which features on our Google Kuberentes Engine respectively on the Google Cloud Platform in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the "Activity" tab within GCP Console. It register all the actions that have been made in the project. Also, you can take a look at Stackdriver Logging and check the Cluster activity logs, it will show you the user that executed the Istio activation.

Comment: And here is the documentation for the Cloud Audit Logs: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/